# jQuery leaveNotice plugin and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

im using leaveNotice plugin and example from authors [page](http://rewdy.com/tools-files/leaveNotice/example.html) (example number six, the last one) On the site all looks all right in both chrome and ie8. When im implement this in my page, in chrome all still looks ok, but ie as usually messed it up. Background appears under the text and pop up appears under the background. It's propably issue with css, but im not have css skills to fix it up. Plus with same css on example site all looks all right, im a lil bit confuse, help me please.
This is what i have in my html

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.leaveNotice.min.js">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.leaveNotice.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="external_link">Google!</a>
```

My js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.external_link').leaveNotice(
    {

        siteName:"LeaveNotice Test Page",
        exitMessage:"<h3>Say goodbye to {SITENAME}!</h3><p>Thanks. Shut the door behind you!</p>",
        preLinkMessage:"<hr/><p>Have fun at:<br/><strong>{URL}</strong></p><hr/>",
        overlayId:"custom-blackout",
        messageBoxId:"custom-messageBox",
        messageBoxHolder:"custom-messageHolder",
        overlayAlpha:0.6

    });

});
```

And my css

```
#custom-blackout {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#514004;}
#custom-messageHolder {position:fixed; top:200px; left:0; width:100%;}
#custom-messageBox {width:400px; margin:0 auto; padding:120px 50px 20px 50px; background:#333 url(img/custom-msg-box-bg.png) no-repeat top center; color:#fff; text-align:center; border:5px solid #F8DA07; -moz-border-radius:15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px;}
#custom-messageBox * {color:#fff;}
#custom-messageBox hr {border-color:#666;}
#custom-messageBox a#ln-cancelLink {background-color:#666; color:#333;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine for me on IE8 for me.

I copied the whole example along with stylesheets from the example into jsfiddle. You can open the following link on IE8 to test it:

http://jsfiddle.net/neebz/gyjVg/1/

I think your problem was with the CSS. You did not style it correctly to show it good enough.

Comment: this is strange, still dont work, please check my code in first post

Comment: It's definitely the problem of not being able to find jQuery.LeaveNotice.css. If I remove the css link of jQuery.LeaveNotice.css from the jsfiddle example and 'Run' (Ctrl+Enter) it then I get the same problem you mentioned. You do realize that in the above code the css file is linked relatively ? Change it to absolute link and see.

Comment: do it from the scratch following manual step by step, all works properly in all browsers except ie :(

Comment: well im work around with css and js and now it's work, cant figure out where's was a mistake, but it's obviously was a stupid mistake, thanks that help me to find it.